# ADFS 2.0 - Proxy / Server 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: wif, adfs2.0

For the past several days I've been working tirelessly to setup a test environment for development with WIF & ADFS 2.0.  One of the problems that I am up against is my home environment only has one IP address and I wasn't about to stick ADFS on my main server. Therefore, I've created a dedicated virtual machine for FS (idp.yyy.local).

*For the sake of not having direct links back to my site, 'yyy' refers to 'dgdev'. (image below)*

The strange thing is, it's partially working. Here is an image detailing my infrastructure.

[image]

What's odd is that I can browse 'idp.yyy.net' in both normal HTTP and HTTPS just fine.  I can also view the WS-Federation Metadata perfectly. Now, I'm quite new to ADFS, but I expect that when going to http://idp.yyy.net/adfs/services/trust it would redirect me to a Windows SSL login.  Instead all I'm receiving is:

Service Unavailable

---

HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

I am using the same SSL certificate on the FS Proxy and FS. Its subject is my main domain name yyy.net.  It has several Subject Alternative Names so that I can host multiple IIS web sites with SSL with my single IP:Port.

```
CN = yyy.net
DNS Name=www.yyy.net
DNS Name=idp.yyy.net
DNS Name=idp.yyy.local
...
IP Address=192.168.1.2
IP Address=192.168.1.3
IP Address=192.168.1.4
...
```

Does anyone have any idea of why I'm seeing 503 Service Unavailable errors. Nothing is showing up in Event Viewer as an error. (*except annoying things with AppFabric, but that's another issue I've yet to touch*)

Thanks in advance! Actually many many thanks. I've exhausted every avenue and idea I could come up with, why this might be "broken"?

---

If anyone has an idea how I can debug this issue I'd certainly except that as a solution.  I've tried IIS Failed Request Logging but nothing is being generated. Where/What is hosting the ADFS Services?
Things I've already looked at:

- All AppPools are running.
- The old ADFS 1.0 web service (asmx) is accessible just fine.
- I can access issuer endpoints directly ... or at least 'windowstransport'

Comment: I should note that some issuer endpoints are working if I go directly to it, like: https://idp.yyy.net/adfs/services/trust/2005/windowstransport.  

Also, the proxy server is returning a 403 Forbidden, but on my local LAN, the actual Federation Server is really returning a 503 Service Unavailable. Not sure why that mis-match exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well turns out everything has been working all along!

I spent a couple hours ensuring the certificate was created properly. Then after still seeing 503 & 403 errors, I realized that my proxy server AppPool for the \Default Web Site was running under "ApplicationPoolIdentity" - which is really the user: 
IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool.

I never gave that user read privileges to the ADFS certificate private key. Hence the reason I saw a 403 Forbidden instead of 503. After switching the AppPool over to Network Service ... voila!, 503 Service Unavailable.

So now I was sure my proxy server and ADFS server were talking just fine. Now why was I still seeing 503 Service Unavailable?!?

I told myself to create a test application anyway.  In visual studio, I setup a new MVC 3 Web App. Added my existing STS-Reference. Setup a dummy claim and updated the application's FederationMetadata.  Added the new Relying Party to ADFS.

Opened my browser to the web app and instant success!

```
> GET) https://mywebapp/
> Response-Redirect) Location header kicks me to my IdP (ADFS)
  https://idp.yyy.net/adfs/ls/?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm.........
> I sign-in with proper credentials
> POST) https://mywebapp/login << AWESOME!
```